# Flutter method not found inside class with new packages

Tags: flutter, methods

Im new in flutter. Still i cant figure out some topics.

I have created a new class and list. I installed new package called sticky headers. when i try to use this package as return statement in class it gives below error;

> Error: Method not found: 'StickyHeader'.

My codes are below;

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:getflutter/components/loader/gf_loader.dart';
import 'package:getflutter/types/gf_loader_type.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:sticky_headers/sticky_headers.dart';

class Application {
  String title;
  String score;
  String icon;
  String googleplay;
  String slug;
  String category;
  String link;

  Application(
      {String title,
      String icon,
      String score,
      String category,
      String link,
      String googleplay,
      String slug})
      : this.title= title,
        this.icon = icon,
        this.category= category,
        this.slug = slug,
        this.googleplay = googleplay,
        this.link= link,
        this.score = score.toString();

  Application.fromJSON(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson)
      : title= parsedJson['title'],
        icon = parsedJson['icon '],
        link= parsedJson['link'],
        category= parsedJson['category'],
        googleplay = parsedJson['googleplay_id'],
        score = parsedJson['score'].toString(),
        slug = parsedJson['slug'];
}

class HomepageView extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<List<Uygulama>>(
      future: _fetchJobs(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          List<Application> data = snapshot.data;

          return gridHeader(data);
        } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Text("${snapshot.error}");
        }
        return GFLoader(type: GFLoaderType.circle);
      },
    );
  }

  Future<List<Application>> _fetchJobs() async {
    final jobsListAPIUrl = 'jsonurl';
    final response = await http.get(jobsListAPIUrl);

    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
      List jsonResponse = json.decode(response.body);
      return jsonResponse
          .map((Application) => new Application.fromJSON(Application))
          .toList();
    } else {
      throw Exception('Failed to load jobs from API');
    }
  }

  Widget gridHeader(data) {
    return new ListView.builder(
      itemCount: data.length,
      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
        return StickyHeader(
          header: Container(
            height: 38.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 12.0),
            alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
            child: Text(
              "New Apps",
              style: const TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.purple,
                  fontSize: 20,
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
          ),
          content: Container(
            child: GridView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
              itemCount: 8,
              gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 2,
                childAspectRatio: 1,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (contxt, indx) {
                return Card(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                  color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 12.0, top: 6.0, bottom: 2.0),
                    child: Center(
                        child: Text(
                      data[indx],
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14, color: Colors.black54),
                    )),
                  ),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
      shrinkWrap: true,
    );
  }
}
```

I want to make homepage screen scollable with multiple gridview with own titles;

Ex:

> New Applciations
>    4 gridview app
>
> Best Application
>   4 gridview app
>
> New Games
>    4 gridview app

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the package at the top of your file like this:

```
import 'package:sticky_headers/sticky_headers.dart';
```

Comment: ı have already imported bro. 

imported again now it gives below erorr;

Error: The method 'StickyHeader' isn't defined for the class 'HomepageView'.

Comment: If it's been imported, it should not give that error. Can you edit your question to show the full code including the imports ?

Comment: Taking a look now

Comment: I don't get the same error after adding the sticky_headers package to my pubspec.yaml. Can you confirm it's in your pubspec?